# How to fix error "this.htmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks is not a function" at "npm run start" command?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

How to fix this **error** I am getting at `npm run start`?

> this.htmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks is not a function npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start:
>   `node scripts/start.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This
>   is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: